# Hangup SIP call when audio file has finished playing

Tags: java, multithreading, audio, sip, rtp

I am using [peers](https://github.com/ymartineau/peers) to implement a SIP UserAgent. Most of the work is already done, thanks to the peers-demo source code and the project documentation.

However, I am having some issues in implementing the following feature: terminating a call after the source (pre-recorded) audio file has finished playing.

Such feature is not available by default, so I am editing the peers-lib project to implement it. In particular, I am currently working on the [RTPSender source code](https://github.com/ymartineau/peers/blob/master/peers-lib/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/peers/media/RtpSender.java) and I do not understand how the run method seems to stop/wait after all data is read from the PipedInputStream encodedData.

At fist, I simply though the the main while cycle:

```
while(!isStopped){
    numBytesRead = 0;
    [...]
}
```

, inside the run method, ended when all data was read from the PipedInputStream mentioned above, but this does not seem the case, since I placed a System.out.println() istruction right after the loop end and it is never executed.

However, that while cycle pauses/ends in some way, because I placed another System.out.println() instruction inside the loop, which stops being executed after the last byte is read from the PipedInputStream.

So I figured it must be related to the thread that runs the code, but I could not find any referece to a sleep()/join() call, but just to a start() call inside the CaptureRtpSender class:

```
[...]
public void start() throws IOException{
    [...]
    rtpSender.setStopped(false);`
    [...]
    Thread rtpSenderThread = new Thread(rtpSender, RtpSender.class.getSimpleName());
    [...]
    rtpSenderThread.start();
}
[...]
```

I think understanding how the thread stops when all data is read, could be the key to solve my problem, since I can then replicate that method to instruct the main class to terminate the call.

Thanks in advance for your help!